# Ошибка SIGSEGV 11 при записи структуры в файл

Tags: c, файлы

Пытаюсь записать структуру в файл в бинарном виде, но постоянно выпадает ошибка `SIGSEGV 11`. не понимаю в чём проблема. Точнее, побочный эффект проявляется, когда записываю строки, в основном. Пытался понять что не так через gdb, но не помогает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

#include "student.h"

int read_student(student* st) {
return scanf("%s,%c,%c,%s,%s\n",
st->name, &st->sex, &st->class, st->university, st->job) == 5;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

student* st = malloc(sizeof(student)); student* prev = malloc(sizeof(student));
FILE* out = fopen(argv[1], "wb");

while (read_student(st)) {
    printf("%s -> ", st->name); 
    if (strcmp(st->name, prev->name)) 
        break;

    *prev = *st;
    fwrite(&st, sizeof(st), 1, out);
    printf("success\n");
}

fclose(out);

return 0;
}
```

Заголовочный файл student.h:

```
#ifndef __applicant_h__
#define __applicant_h__

typedef struct {
    char name[50]; // фамилия и инициалы
    char sex; // пол
    char class; // буква класса
    char university[50]; // университет 
    char job[30]; // место работы
} student;

#endif
```

Запускаю в терминале так: `(./student.o data.bin) < data.txt`

Тестовые данные выглядят так (data.txt):
Artyom A.C.,m,A,Moscow Aviation Institute,Mobile TeleSystem
Maria S.K.,f,B,Moscow State University,Unemployed

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну а память кто выделять будет за вас под структуру `st`?

Comment: @ヒミコ сейчас протестирую, сделал так `malloc(sizeof(st))` не помогает

Comment: `fwrite(&st, sizeof(st)` записывает указатель, который вы никогда не инициализировали...

Comment: @user7860670 обновил, не помогает

Comment: Так а `prev` тоже никогда не инициализируется...

Comment: @user7860670 опять не помогает

Comment: Тут видно только могила поможет... Начните наконец инициализировать объекты перед их использованием.

Comment: первый раз в prev мусор, потом prev присваивается указатель st, а не значение, то есть на strcmp вышибает

Comment: @PavelGridin так я не могу воткнуть туда *, потому что будет * = **. Если вы про &, то он собственно и выдаёт предупреждение. А вообще оно даже не заходит в цикл, подозреваю, ошибка где-то в read_student

Comment: если присваивать значение структуры то надо `*prev = *st;`, я вот что-то засомневался, а для `%c` не адрес ли `int` нужен?

Comment: @PavelGridin так там ведь и стоит адрес, вы же про &st->class и &st->sex?

Comment: @PavelGridin До присваивания здесь даже не доходит...

Comment: я имел ввиду не надо ли описывать sex и class, как int, вот ведь для %f надо double, а не float

Comment: @PavelGridin вообще, можно, по идее, но в доках printf говорят юзать %c. Только я не понимаю, он как только пытается считать что угодно сразу вылетает, не понимаю почему.

Comment: вообще лучше строку сначала ввести, потом sscanf

Comment: @PavelGridin В общем, я попробовал, оно почему-то не считывает дальше пробела первого.

Comment: @PavelGridin всё, я придумал что можно сделать, но не уверен, что это наиболее правильный способ, попутно нашёл пару косяков, утром заполню ответ, но такого я не ожидал от си, конечно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Много, слишком много несуразиц.

Ну, пусть вы не забыли передать имя файла и таки открыли его (вы не проверяете, ни передано ли его имя, ни открылся ли он).

Но дальше при чтении с помощью `%s` вы читаете одно слово, за которым нет запятой, и благополучно выходите из цикла - `scanf` возвращает не 5, а 1. Кстати, кто мешал вам вывести хотя бы отладочную запись и посмотреть, что же происходит на самом деле?

Дальше - когда вы исправите, например, как `scanf("%[^,],%c,%c,%[^,],%[^\n]"`, вы пытаетесь использовать неинициализированную память `prev`. Не то чтоб *в данном случае* это было сильно страшно, но очень нехорошо. Особенно в других случаях, где это важно.

Вы сравниваете `strcmp(st->name, prev->name)`, а поскольку там мусор (в `prev->name`), можно спорить, что строки *не* равны, а значит, функция `strcmp` вернет не ноль, и вы вылетаете из цикла...

Но даже если вы исправите и это, то потом вы записываете в файл значение *указателя*, а не того, на что указатель указывает. Вам точно нужно именно это?

По-моему, вы хотели

```
fwrite(st, sizeof(student), 1, out);
```

[Грустно] Скажите после этого - а что вы делаете "так"?... И, кстати, нигде ни одну ошибку не проверяете (ну, попытались только со `scanf`)...

Comment: Да, всё так, в записи случайно стоял адрес вместо самого значения. А проверки я убрал чтобы меньше было кода для вопроса. Кстати, я как раз делал проверку с помощью regex, почему это работает? Только я делал sscanf, вместо scanf, ведь если судить по документации он не умеет читать пробелы

Comment: `sscanf` и `scanf` отличаются единственным - один читает из строки, другой из `stdin`, в остальном они *абсолютно* идентичны.

Comment: Вот здесь написано https://www.knowprogram.com/c-programming/read-and-display-the-string-in-c-programming/, что scanf читает до первого пробела, разве нет? Я просто пытаюсь понять, почему scanf не может считать без regex. И почему он вообще считывает при наличии пробелов

Comment: `scanf` читает до, что ему говорят. `%s` - да, первое слово. Почитайте тут - https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

Comment: Кстати, вот - https://ideone.com/oiu9m4